# Combine/Concatenate Arrays Side by Side

Tags: php, arrays, merge

What is the most simple way to concatenate two arrays to become side by side?

Here is $Arr1

```
Array
(
    [0] => Windows
)
```

and here is $Arr2

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5.0
)
```

How would I combine them so that `$Arr[0] = "Windows5.0"`?

`array_merge($Arr1, $Arr2)` Adds `$Arr2` to be *below* `$Arr1` which is not what I want

Comment: Have you tried imploding the result of array_merge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$Arr1 = Array ( "Windows");
$Arr2 = Array ( " 5.0");

$arr = array( $Arr1[0] . $Arr2[0] );
var_dump($arr);
```

**ouput**

```
array (size=1)
  0 => string 'Windows 5.0' (length=11)
```

Answer (score 3):

[array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) may work for you as long as each array is equal length and the keys are valid.  This will structure your data better and then you can use a foreach loop.

```
<?php
  $a = array('Windows', 'Mac', 'Linux');
  $b = array('5.0', '6.0', '3.14');
  $c = array_combine($a, $b);

  print_r($c);
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
Array
(
  [Windows]  => 5.0
  [Mac]    => 6.0
  [Linux] => 3.14
)
```

So if you need to get the value for Windows it would be:

```
<?php
  foreach($c as $key => value) {
    echo $key." ".$value."\n";
 }
```

?>

Which would display:

```
Windows 5.0
Mac 6.0
Linux 3.14
```

Answer (score 1):

For your particular example, after you do array_merge, do implode on the resulting array, this will give you the desired output.

```
$Arr = [implode(array_merge($Arr1, $Arr2))]; // works for PHP 5.4+
$Arr = array(implode(array_merge($Arr1, $Arr2))) // for older versions
```

I have a suspicion that your requirements are a little more complex than that.

For more info on `implode`, see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

If you would like to join the values from multiple entries, try using `array_map`:

```
$Arr1 = array('windows', 'floor', 'door');
$Arr2 = array('5.0', '6.0', '7.0');
$Arr = array_map(function($a, $b) { return $a . $b; }, $Arr1, $Arr2);
```

This will output:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => windows5.0
        [1] => floor6.0
        [2] => door7.0
    )
```

For more info on `array_map`, see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Answer (score 0):

This will work -- espacially interesting when doing with multiple values:

```
foreach ($arr1 as $key=>$value)
{
    $arr3[] = $value.$arr2[$key];

}

var_dump($arr3);
```

**output**:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "Windows5.0" }
```